# MS Access error on opening database

Tags: ms-access-2007

I work with Access daily, and this situation is unlike anything I've ever seen Access do:

I created a database tool in Access for a report I run at work.  The other day I was using it, and Access abruptly closed itself down.  I went to reopen the tool, and I got an error saying "Microsoft Access has stopped working.  A problem has caused the program to stop working correctly.  Windows will close the program and notify you when a solution is available."

A few minutes later it prompts me to create a backup, which also does the same thing when I try to open it...

...unless...

I open Access itself and search for the original tool.  Then it opens just fine.

I have tried repairing this database, and nothing works.  It simply won't let me open this tool unless I go through Access first.

Does anyone have any ideas on this?  What gives???

(Windows 7 Enterprise Edition, MS Access 2007)

Answer (score 0):

A few things I would try

1) Create an entirely new DB, and import all of the objects from the problematic database. Any corrupt objects will show as an error during that process. You may get lucky and the new DB can simply be the new production DB.

2) Hold down the Shift key as Access is loading to bypass any startup code.

The problem is likely in the VBA link, which the new DB shell will fix.